# Handle OTP from pgina

Tags: c#, winlogon, gina, windows-credential-provider

I'm using pGina open source project for winlogon process. I want to add new text field on windows logon screen with "Otp" field.
Basically, I want to create and handle otp field into windows logon screen.
-Username, -Password, -Otp.
Anyone use pGina and can help about this issue?

Comment: Have a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52478238/3868464) and it's answers.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I checked your answer but I got some errors while build my project. I've changed TileUILogon.h and TileUiLogonTypes.h files according to answers but it gives an error like "cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'DWORD'". Can you share a path which files should I change ?